# Measure of $\lbrace (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \leq 1 \rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have to determine the measue of $$\Delta_n=\lbrace (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \leq 1, x_k \geq 0, k=1,...,n \rbrace$$
The hint that I have is express $\Delta_n$ in terms of $\Delta_{n-1}$.

My attempt was to calculate the case $n = 2$ and $n = 3$, where I got $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ respectively. From there I could write the measure of $\Delta_n$ as
$$\int_{\Delta_{n-1}}dx_{n-1} \cdots dx_1 \int_{x_n=0}^{1- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}}dx_n$$
and from there integrate step by step. The problem is that I think it is too long a process and I would like to know if there is a faster way to find the measure of $\Delta_n$.

Note: I was able to write the previous expression since in the cases $n = 2$ I wrote:
$$\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{1-x}dydx$$
and for the case $n=3$ :
$$\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_{z=0}^{1-x-y}dzdydx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, let $f_n(x)$ be (for $x\geqslant 0$ and $n>0$) the measure of $$\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}_+^n : \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\leqslant x\right\}.$$ Then $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_n(x)=\int_0^x f_{n-1}(x-x_n)\,dx_n$ for $n>1$.

By induction, $f_n(x)=x^n/n!$, and the answer is $f_n(1)=1/n!$.

Comment: I do not see why it is true that $f_n(x)= \int_{0}^{x} f_{n-1}(x-x_n)dx_n$. Can you explain in more detail, please?